# trigger NgbModal without a button but via function call

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

All the examples in [Angular Bootstrap's Modals](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) have an external button to trigger the modal itself.

In my case I am using a Diagram, which has a function `nodeClicked(event, node)`.

In the function I check whether the user has pressed the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button whilst clicking the node. If not, I need to trigger a Modal stating that the button is not clicked.

**component.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>NO <kbd>CTRL</kbd> Button Pressed.</p>
        <p>If previous Selection were selected using Multiselect Feature, they will be deleted.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

within the `nodeClicked()` function:

**component.ts**

```
constructor (modal: NgbModal) {}
....
nodeClicked(ev, node) {

if (ev.control) {
  //perform necessary stuff
}
else {
  this.modal.open() // here according to API I need to pass content.
  // but I already have mentioned that in `modal-body`
}

}
```

How Can i Trigger my Modal without actually passing the `content` string in the `this.model.open()` method call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a reference to the modal template with `@ViewChild("content")` in the component code, and pass it to `NgbModal.open`. As an example, [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OCP9GDaNvZTi1VSzCUrd) displays the modal automatically after 5 seconds.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild("content") modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {
  }

  nodeClicked(ev, node) {
    if (ev.control) {
      //perform necessary stuff
    }
    else {
      this.modal.open(this.modalContent).result.then((result) => {
        ...
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does that imply that I can call `this.showModal()` within a function viz. `nodeClicked()`?

Comment: You can do that, yes. Or you can call `this.modal.open(this.modalContent)` directly in `nodeClicked` (I will update my answer).